# Is this considered a best practice to extend PySpark Dataframe with a Python class?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm designing an ETL which would actually be a Spark job, written in Python. This is the ML model pre-training process, in which I enrich the data, complete missing values, execute different kinds of aggregation, filtering, and so on, bringing the raw data to the point, it is ready for feature processing.

What is the best practice to work with a Dataframe when I also need to change different config files according to the data, perform a lot of logic, combine Dataframes from multiple sources, and want it to be still readable, testable, etc?

I thought might it be good to stick with the transform pipeline composition we are familiar with and extend the Dataframe so a python class will wrap it with all the methods and members I need for each data source.

I don't know if it is considered best practice, what do you think? Is there a better way to deal with it?

Another question on the same subject - talking about this idea, I can think of two ways to do that -

The first -

```
class EnrichedDataframe:

    def __init__(self, df, *args):
        self.df = df
        self.args = args

    def func1(self):
        self.df = self.df.doSomeLogic()
        return self

    def func2(self):
        self.df = self.df.doSomeLogic()
        return self

    def func3(self):
        self.df = self.df.doSomeLogic()
        return self
```

The second -

```
class EnrichedDataframe(DataFrame):

    def __init__(self, df, *args):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(df._jdf, df.sql_ctx)
        self.df = df
        self.args = args
        
    def func1(self):
        df = self.df.doSomeLogic()
        return EnrichDataframe(df, self.args)

    def func2(self):
        df = self.df.doSomeLogic()
        return EnrichDataframe(df, self.args)

    def func3(self):
        df = self.df.doSomeLogic()
        return EnrichDataframe(df, self.args)
```

Which one is better, and why? Or maybe it doesn't matter?

Comment: [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) is a good general rule to keep in mind.

Comment: According to this principle, the first approach is better, right? It's a good point, sounds logical and more flexible indeed, even though I meant to ask it from the perspective of efficiency If it even matters anyway